# Accessing part of std_logic_vector using variables as indexes

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to access a part of `std_logic_vector` using variables as indexes.

The following process gets a `shift_val` result from a function and then uses it to calculate the indexes to extract the 6-bit data we need in `shift_data_in_s`

> **I am getting a simulation error on the last line:**
>
> `shift_data_in_s <= data_in_e(to_integer(unsigned(msb_pos)) downto to_integer(unsigned(lsb_pos)))`
>
> **saying "Array size of 6 on LHS does not match the array size of 1 on
>   RHS"**

I thought the initialization on `lsb_pos` and `msb_pos` would solve this problem but it didnt... not sure how it gets the same value for both these variables, if I am explicitly computing them by subtracting the same value from different constants.

```
signal shift_val_s      : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal shift_data_in_s  : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
shift_in_proc : process( data_in, num_zeros_s )

variable data_in_e      : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
variable msb_pos        : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := "01110";
variable lsb_pos        : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := "01001";
begin
  data_in_e := data_in & zeros_f(16 - data_in'length); 
  shift_val_s <= some_function(data_in_e);
  if ( to_integer(unsigned(shift_val)) >= 12) then
   -- all zeros
  shift_data_in_s <= ( others => '0');
  else
  -- we need only 6 significant bits from the data, 
  -- msb_pos <= 15 - num_zeros -1;
  msb_pos := std_logic_vector( "01110" - unsigned(('0' & shift_val_s))); 
  -- lsb_pos <= 15 - num_zeros -6;
  lsb_pos := std_logic_vector("01001" -  unsigned(('0' & shift_val_s))); 
  if ( lsb_pos(4) = '1') then -- if -ve
    shift_data_in_s <= data_in_e(to_integer(unsigned(msb_pos)) downto 0) & zeros_f( to_integer(unsigned(neg_f(lsb_pos))));
  else
    shift_data_in_s <= data_in_e(to_integer(unsigned(msb_pos)) downto to_integer(unsigned(lsb_pos)));
  end if;
 end if ; end process shift_in_proc;
```

Comment: This isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without that you're getting experience based opinions instead of fact based answers - "most likely explanation", "not possible for anyone here to directly diagnose ". You also assign signal shift_val_s in the process and later use it in right hand expressions without an intervening wait statement. It appears you want a variable here? Or constant, `data_in'length` is from a declared index range, gets rid of `some_function` as well as `data_in_e` metastability value issues.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that `msb_pos` and `lsb_pos` contain a metavalue (ie. non-`01HL` data), presumably because `data_in` is invalid. The `to_integer` calls would then both return 0, giving you a range of 1, not 6. In any event, you can find out quickly using your simulator.

**EDIT**

Quick fix, as per your comment: make sure that `some_function` always returns a non-metavalue 4-bit vector. There are lots of ways to do this, but you could simply do:

```
fixed_answer <= to_01(metaval_answer); -- remove metavals
```

There's a `to_01` in `numeric_std`, which takes an `unsigned` and returns an `unsigned`. By default, metavalues are converted to zero. You'll still get the wrong answer at the breginning of simulation, but at least the sim will carry on.

Comment: yes you are right at time 0, data_in is invalid..but I dont know how to to get around this problem

Answer (score 0):

The value of your variable `lsb_pos` is dependent on `shift_val_s`, which is itself dependent on `some_function` - the code for which you have not provided.  So it is not possible for anyone here to directly diagnose the problem.

Incidentally your code would be easier to read if you use `integer` variables, e.g.:

```
variable msb_pos        : integer range 0 to 31 := 14;
variable lsb_pos        : integer range 0 to 31 := 9;
```

The last line then becomes:

```
shift_data_in_s <= data_in_e(msb_pos downto lsb_pos);
```

If your `some_function` returns an integer you can calculate your `msb_pos` as such:

```
msb_pos := 14 - shift_val_s;
lsb_pos := 9 - shift_val_s;
```

Comment: thanks...agree that msb_pos and lsb_pos depend on shift_val_s ..but shift_val_s is a 4 bit vector..no matter what its value is, shouldnt I get a different values for msb_pos and lsb_pos?